# Kafka Stream Creation for Nested JSON Array Structure

Tags: json, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

I am trying to read data from a Kafka topic which has below Nested Array JSON structure.

```
{
    "case1": {
        "case2": [
            {
                "case3A": {
                    "var1": "xx",
                    "var2": "xx",
                    "var3": "xx"
                },
                "case3B": {
                    "var4": "xx",
                    "var5": "xx",
                    "var6": "xx"
                },
                "case3C": {
                    "var7": "xx",
                    "var8": "xx",
                    "var9": "xx"
                }
            },
            {
                "case3A": {
                    "var1": "xx",
                    "var2": "xx",
                    "var3": "xx"
                },
                "case3B": {
                    "var4": "xx",
                    "var5": "xx",
                    "var6": "xx"
                },
                "case3C": {
                    "var7": "xx",
                    "var8": "xx",
                    "var9": "xx"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am trying to read the variables through KsqlDB Streams from this topic. I tried with Array & Struct.  However I am not able to find correct combination of functions which I can use to extract the fields on this stream. Any help in this much appreciated.

I was able to get the fields from case1 now. However I had to explicitly mention array numbers in the query. Here it would return variable in specific to the array number. In real time, we may get any number of array counts. I am looking for like explode function in this to return all the array variables. do we have any workaround for this.

```
CREATE STREAM Stream1 (case1 VARCHAR) 
WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='testtopic', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON', PARTITIONS=6); 

SELECT 
EXTRACTJSONFIELD(case1,'$.case2[0].case3A.var1'), 
EXTRACTJSONFIELD(case1,'$.case2[0].case3B.var4')
FROM Stream1
```

Comment: case2 is the only array. Can you share what you tried? Also, since the other cases have no consistent names, you need to use maps, not structs

Comment: I was able to read the data from case2 array with below stream & qry.I got struck when I have case1 on top of the array element.
Note- This is not a real data. I mocked the data to show my JSON strcuture. I corrected the mocked data now for array element now.
CREATE STREAM Stream1 (case2 ARRAY<VARCHAR>)
 WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='testtopic',
       VALUE_FORMAT='JSON',
       PARTITIONS=6);
       
SELECT 
EXTRACTJSONFIELD(EXPLODE(case2),'$.case3A.var1'),
EXTRACTJSONFIELD(EXPLODE(case2),'$.case3B.var4'),
EXTRACTJSONFIELD(EXPLODE(case2),'$.case3C.var8')
FROM Stream1
EMIT CHANGES;

Comment: I was able to get the fields from case1 now. However I had to explicitly mention array numbers. In real time, we may get any number of array counts. 
I am looking for like explode function in this. do we have any workaround for this. 

CREATE STREAM Stream1 (case1 VARCHAR) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='testtopic', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON', PARTITIONS=6); 

SELECT 
EXTRACTJSONFIELD(case1,'$case2[0].case3A.var1'), 
EXTRACTJSONFIELD(case1,'$case2[0].case3B.var4'), 
EXTRACTJSONFIELD(case1,'$case2[1].case3A.var1'), 
EXTRACTJSONFIELD(case1,'$case2[1].case3B.var4') 
FROM Stream1

Comment: Sorry, I cannot read that code. Please [edit] your question to include the code as formatted text

Comment: @OneCricketeer I updated my question with the formatted code now. Basically I am looking for explode like logic to return all array variables. Each array element should be reported into one row.

Comment: `EXPLODE(EXTRACTJSONFIELD(case1,'$.case2'))` doesn't work? The explode function definitely exists https://rmoff.net/2020/05/26/working-with-json-nested-arrays-in-ksqldb-example/

Comment: Explode function only works for Array field. The EXTRACTJSONFIELD returns the output with String data type. So it doesn't work here.

Comment: Then create a second stream with $.case1.case2 as an array or parse/cast it another way

Comment: Or use a map type https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/reference/sql/data-types/#compound-types

Comment: I was able to get required output with Struct function and by creating a 2nd stream. Thanks @OneCricketeer for your inputs. I have one more question. My consumer will be Oracle DB. Can we directly load the data from stream to Consumer Oracle DB or the stream data needs to be written into another topic to load the data into downstream oracle DB.